# Race Condition when calling node.js service from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have two node service calls I make: one to get the group members from an LDAP group and the other to get each members details.  Each call is non-blocking with callbacks so I'm running into a situation where sometimes the record I'm on isn't matching up with the details retrieved for the individual.

Is there a clever way to code this to prevent the race condition? Sometimes it works but often on the line where I'm doing the console log below, the record I'm iterating on is not matched up with the one returned from the store to get the employee details. Here's a look at the code:

```
onGroupSelected: function (list, idx, el, record) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('GroupMembers');
    store.getProxy().setUrl('http://people-nodejs.xxx.xxx.com/ldap/group/' + record.get('cn'));
    var that = this;
    store.load({
        callback: function (records, operation) {
            var empstore = Ext.getStore('EmployeeDetails');
            Ext.each(records, function(rec, ndx) {
                console.log(ndx + ":" + rec.get('memberUid'));
                if (rec.get('isMember')) {
                    empstore.getProxy().setUrl('http://people-nodejs.xxx.xxx.com/ldap/user/' + rec.get('memberUid'));
                    empstore.load({
                        callback: function(emps, op) {
                            console.log(ndx + ":" + rec.get('memberUid') + "--" + emps[0].get('fullName'));
                            rec.set('workforceID', emps[0].get('workforceID'));
                            rec.set('fullName', emps[0].get('fullName'));
                            that.getGroupMembersList().setRecord(rec);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            // Remove empty records and populate with records from above
            store.removeAll();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a single threaded environment, like Javascript (and node.js), you can't really have race conditions.

Instead you are running into javascript closures and a misunderstanding as to how variables work in nested functions and loops.

`rec` is defined inside you `Ext.each(records, function(rec, ndx)`, and inside your callback function, you are making use of it's value, with the assumption that for each iteration, `rec` is still bound to the same value when when the callback was executed.

This is incorrect, and instead the value of `rec` is bound at the time the callback function is executed, not at the time the function is created (this is, in essence, the definition of a closure).

So instead for this to work the way you expect, you will need to force `rec` to be bound during creation, by doing something like (note: syntax may have issues):

```
callback: (function(myrec,index){ 
    return function(emps, op) {
      console.log(index + ":" + myrec.get('memberUid') + "--" + emps[0].get('fullName'));
      myrec.set('workforceID', emps[0].get('workforceID'));
      myrec.set('fullName', emps[0].get('fullName'));
      that.getGroupMembersList().setRecord(myrec);
    };)(rec,ndx);
```

In the example above, we're executing an anonymous javascript function immediately, passing in the value `rec` which gets bound by `myrec` at creation time. The anonymous function returns a function with the same signature that the callback expects, and when your callback executes the function, it will have the proper value for `rec`

Comment: A browser client isn't single threaded as it makes simultaneous calls to the node.js service for the emps details.  You bring up a good point though; however, even after correcting the closure, this change still yields the same result of users being duplicated. :(

Comment: Each call your client to the server should be "self-contained" by node, as if it were executed on it's own thread, unless you were making use of global variables inside your handler. If you are seeing issues caused by multiple calls to your server api, then I suspect you have another closure related issue higher up on the call stack (perhaps in the code that invokes `onGroupSelected`)?

Comment: Or perhaps this code: `var empstore = Ext.getStore('EmployeeDetails');` Javascript's event queue will execute synchronously, until it awaits further IO (and get placed back on the event queue). So it's very possible that `empstore` is loaded with the same user twice. I would use a double-check solution for this. Essentially see if empstore already contains the record you are trying to load, before loading it.

Comment: I've looked up the stack, and no other callbacks. The empstore only can contain one record at a time (it searches each employee from the previous store -- the group members), so what I did is isolate this bit of functionality into a separate function and check to see if emps.uid === myrec.uid. If not, I make a recursive call to try again.  Ugly I realize, but node is so freaking fast you can't even tell from the UI.  I'm at a loss to find a better solution at the moment.